# In microwave frequencies, do you use a circulator when you need a (near) perfect diode?

Tags: diodes, microwave

I am confused with the "diode concept" in microwave frequencies. As far as I could read, I found that even small signal Schottky diodes have a non negligible capacitance, that may perturb the signal from 1GHz and more (well I've seen a few that work up to 20GHz but they require special mounting etc.). 
On the other hand, there are circulators with operating frequencies from 1GHz to 40GHz, and I think they can be used as a diode since a signal entering at port 1 output at port 2 but the inverse path is blocked. Hence my question: is it what microwave engineers use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Diodes and circulators are totally different components.

Microwave engineers use one when they want one, the other when they want the other. They use diodes when they want to rectify signals, and circulators when they want to isolate ports.

Comment: So, what do you do if you need to rectify signals at 40GHz?

Comment: @MikeTeX you can use a very tiny diode. It would be more likely called a "power detector" than a "rectifier".

Comment: OK. Just the answer to the question. This helped me to understand what a circulator really is. The other answers give complements though.

Answer (score 3):

In short, no, one would not use a circulator when one needs a diode.

A circulator can't perform the same functions diodes can. For example, diodes can be used as an RF switch (pass RF when supplied with a DC bias, block RF and leave a high-impedance output when no bias is applied), which a circulator cannot do.

Comment: This is interesting. I never thought using a diode with a bias tee as a switch. But why not use simply a microwave transistor for this task?

Comment: @MikeTeX Cost, control circuitry (two terminal device instead of 3-terminal), switch performance, power handling, etc.

Answer (score 3):

At microwave frequencies one might use a biased **pin diode** in a duplex port to protect (Block) the Rx LNA input while Tx out on the same coax to the antenna.

However, using a **Circulator is somewhat** like a Directional coupler except it is **undirectional ( in only one direction of the circle ) or "non-reciprocal"** feeding only to the next port.

They are made in 3 port and 4 port version.

- To achieve isolation and amplification one might choose **tunnel diodes or Gunn diodes** which due to their avalanche effects have a **Negative Differential Resistance**

  - Then the diode can block the Rx during Tx mode and amplify during Rx mode with proper bias on the diode in a circulator. This is a half-duplex Rx/Tx microwave method used for higher bands of microwave.

[image] [*[Ref][2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Negative_resistance_amp.svg#filelinks)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Negative_resistance_amp.svg)

[image] *[Ref](http://www.novamicro.com/understanding-circulator-and-isolaters.php)*

[image]  *[Ref](http://www.dpvrf.com/Coaxial_Circulators.html)*

Comment: Thank you for this nice answer, full of side information.